# Base64 String to byte[] in java

Tags: java, string, base64, byte, encoder-decoder

I am trying to convert base64 String to byte array but it is throwing following error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3a

I have tried following options userimage is base64 string

```
byte[] img1 = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(userimage);`

/* byte[] decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString.getBytes(UTF_8));*/
/* byte[] byteimage =Base64.getDecoder().decode( userimage );*/
/* byte[] byteimage =  Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(userimage);*/`
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use `java.util.Base64` package to decode the String to `byte[]`. 
Below code which I have used for encode and decode.

For Java 8 :

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            byte[] name = Base64.getEncoder().encode("hello World".getBytes());
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(new String(name).getBytes("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println(new String(decodedString));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

For Java 6 :

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            byte[] name = Base64.encodeBase64("hello World".getBytes());
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decodeBase64(new String(name).getBytes("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println(new String(decodedString));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! Remember that if a web browser is posting a image as Base64, you should desconsider the beggining of the string `data:image/jpeg;base64,`. You can use `new String(base64Image.substring(base64Image.indexOf(",") + 1)).getBytes("UTF-8"));`